# semicontinuity implies sequential semicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I have that $F:X\to (-\infty,+\infty]$, with $X$ topological space.
By definition, $F$ is lower semicontinuous in $x_0 \in X$ if
$\forall t \in \mathbb{R}: \. t<F(x_0) \.\exists U\in \mathcal{U}(x_0): \. t<F(x_0) \. \forall x \in U  $.
I've seen that $F$ is lsc in $x_0$ $\iff$ $F(x_0) \le\sup_{U \in \mathcal{U}(x_0)} \inf_{x \in U} f(x)$.
Now I'd like to prove that $F$ is lsc in $x_0$ $\iff$ $F(x_0) \le \liminf_{x_n\to x_0} \. \forall x_n \to x_0 $
Any hint?! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

$F$ is lsc at $x_0$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $F(x_0) \leq \liminf_{x_n\rightarrow x_0} F(x_n)$ $\forall x_n \rightarrow x_0$ in $\mathcal{T}$.

I assume you are trying to prove $\Rightarrow$, since $\Leftarrow$ is only true if the space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is first-countable.

**Hint:** suppose there exists a sequence $x_n \rightarrow x$ such that 
$$F(x_0) > \liminf_{x_n\rightarrow x_0} F(x_n),$$
or the relaxed version of above inequality
$$F(x_0) \geq \liminf_{x_n\rightarrow x_0} F(x_n) +\epsilon$$
for some $\epsilon >0$, then argue by contrapositive, try to show that $F$ can not be lsc.

Observe that for any $U\in\mathcal{U}(x_0)$, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have $x_n\in U$.